# "failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed" only when trying to access T-Mobile.com

Tags: ssl, openssl, curl, tls

I have 2 phones, 2 tablets, and 2 laptops can log into my account at T-Mobile with no issues.

My main PC, (Alienware R11 running Win11) cannot access my T-Mobile account. It gets an error when trying to access T-Mobile.

> Hmmm… can't reach this page
> It looks like the webpage at https://www.t-mobile.com/ might be having issues,
> or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
> ERR_FAILED

I have tried Edge, Chrome, cURL, and openssl to connect. I have found no other URL that I cannot connect to. I have no issues connecting to T-Mobile on any other device.

Any suggestions to resolve?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl -v https://www.t-mobile.com
*   Trying 2a02:e980:e6::67:443...
* Connected to www.t-mobile.com (2a02:e980:e6::67) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Send failure: Connection was reset
* schannel: failed to send initial handshake data: sent -1 of 202 bytes
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Send failure: Connection was reset
```

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>openssl s_client -connect www.t-mobile.com:443 -tlsextdebug -showcerts
CONNECTED(0000019C)
write:errno=10054
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 322 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

No security software, vpn, ad/spyware installed (that I am aware of). System just has stock what Alienware installed, plus upgrade from Win 10 to 11.

Booting into "Safe Mode with Network" does not allow access to internet (cat5 or wifi).

Network controller is an Intel Killer E3000 2.5 Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

Every URL that I test works with no issue, except T-Mobile. And T-Mobile claims issue is on my end.

Comment: Don't use T-mobile https://www.opensecrets.org/political-action-committees-pacs/t-mobile-usa/C00361758/summary/2020

Comment: *"SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 322 bytes"* - this looks like something is blocking the connection. Given that this is only this specific system it might be some security software installed on the system itself or that the system is connected in a different way than others (like using a VPN to some company network).

Comment: do you have a pihole server, or any kind of ad/spyware blocking software on the system in  question?

Comment: Try when booting into Safe Mode with Network (if your network works in this mode).

Comment: @harrymc Booted into Safe Mode with Network.  Network (cat5) does not work. Maybe issues with drivers under Safe Mode.  Network controller is an Intel Killer E3000 2.5 Gigabit Ethernet Controller.  

Every URL that I test works with no issue, except T-Mobile. And T-Mobile claims issue is on my end.